# Datetime error on Mono.data.Sqlite

Tags: c#, android, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.android

Following the last upgrade of the the xamrin environment is no longer possible to perform the queries, which filter is composed with datetime condition.

While leaving all conditions unchanged:  same source code, same database structure and the data in the tables; the solution compiled with the previous framework (until August 2016) return always the correct records, after install the last framework the query return 0 result.

```
using (SqliteCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
  cmd.CommandText = " SELECT * FROM SP_ARTMGZ WHERE DATE_SPED=@DATESPED ";
  cmd.Parameters.Clear();
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DATESPED", dtDateSped);
  conn.Open();
  using (SqliteDataAdapter da = new SqliteDataAdapter(cmd))
  {
   da.Fill(result);
  }
}
```

---

```
=== Xamarin Studio Professional ===
Version 6.1.2 (build 44)
Installation UUID: 8716ded3-7f56-49d6-b5ac-f2c7597eef3f
Runtime:
Microsoft .NET 4.0.30319.42000
GTK+ 2.24.26 (Light theme)
GTK# 2.12.38
=== NuGet ===
Versione: 3.4.3.0
=== Xamarin.Android ===
Versione: 7.0.2.37 (Visual Studio Professional)
Android SDK: C:\Users\Giovanni\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk
Versione di Android supportate:
4.0.3  (livello API 15)
4.4    (livello API 19)
4.4.87 (livello API 20)
5.0    (livello API 21)
5.1    (livello API 22)
6.0    (livello API 23)
7.0    (livello API 24)
```

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=46929

Comment: Did you tried `new SQLiteParameter("@DATESPED", SqlDbType.Date) { Value = dtDateSped};` I mean,specifying the data type?

Comment: We also tried this syntax but still doesn't work.
The source code, without any change, has stopped to working correctly, after install the Xamarin enviroment upgrade of August (stable version).